# Unable to Commit Git Changes. Error Message: fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'refs/heads/master': reference broken

Tags: git

I am getting the above error when tryping to commit changes in my repo.
`git gc` returns the following:

```
error: bad ref for .git/logs/HEAD
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/heads/master
error: bad ref for .git/logs/HEAD
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/heads/master
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object 3ee0ce38a1503fa8a00412a81ea64965c85d8943 (stored in .git/objects/3e/e0ce38a1503fa8a00412a81ea64965c85d8943) is corrupt
error: failed to run repack
```

I don't really know how to resolve this sort of thing and other answers I have found to similar questions haven't done the trick.

Comment: This appears to be a corrupted repository. Search for `git repository corrupt`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the only quick way I could find to fix this was to clone the repo into a different location and then re-make any changes from the other location of the repo. Not really a fix but a work around and took 10 minutes all-in-all.